# App ignoring initial catalog attribute from connection string

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, connection-string, integrated-security

I do face a rather strange behavior at customer site:

My ASP.NET application tries to connect to a database using a connection string, specified in the web.config.

This works fine in all cases but one - this specific customer needed to switch integrated security on, due to security permissions.
Strangely, now the application tries to connect to another database and not the one defined as 'initial catalog'.

I've already double-checked the connection string for any typos.

There are no USE statements in the queries. Basically there's nothing else telling the application where to connect to but this connection string.

If relevant - it is using the EntityClient provider.

The connection string (some parts changed of course):

```
<add name="ConnName" connectionString="metadata=... provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: You are asking a question about connection string without actually showing us the connection string? Can you please provide it?

Comment: show us some code...

Comment: @Ruskin: Added the connection string.

Comment: @Thorarins: Which part of the code would be relevant in your oppinion? The Model is directly bound to this connection string, connection is done by EF, no special code involved.

Comment: So now you have 2 connectionstrings in your web config? One for this client and another for the others or something? You're sure it's using the correct one?

Comment: Judging from the connection string snippet you posted I don't see anything peculiar, need more information about that one query you say which doesn't use the initial catalog.  Have you changed the order in which the queries run and checked?  What kind of query is it? A simple EF enumeration? Or do you exec custom store queries/stored proc?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: No, it's only this one connection string - software is installed at customer site.

Comment: @Ruskin:Nothing special here - take this as an example:

    using(var ctx = new Entity()){
        var res = ctx.Jobs.Where(...).ToList(...);
    }

So yes, a simple EF enumeration.
As mentioned before, I never choose a specific database by code.

Comment: Does the user logged into the machine (as its using windows security) have a default database set up? Do they have access to the database "DB" which was set in the original connection string?

Comment: @Ruskin: I'm already waiting to get this information from their DBA.
At least the access is working fine - MS SQL Server Management Studio does successfully connect using Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved - there is a View involved which hasn't been created correctly and was pointing to that other database.